# How to limit a if else statment?

Tags: java

I am trying to limit the user from overfeeding a virtual cat by making it only if health level is less than 60 they can feed it.Also if user attempts to feed cat when health is over 60 then happiness decreases by 2 for option 1. I tried `health < 60;` but it gives me an error.This is different because it is limiting not comparing strings. different question not even sure why it's marked.

```
int food = 20;
int health = 30;
int happiness = 80;
String option;
System.out.println("pick an option ");
System.out.println(" Option 1 feed cat ");
System.out.println(" Option 2 play with cat");
System.out.println(" Option 3 give cat bath");
option = input.nextLine();
if(option == 1) {
    food += 10;
    happiness -= 15
    health < 60;
    happiness -=2;
} else if (option == 2) {
    happiness += 12;
    health += 25;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `options = input.nextLine();`  There is no variable `option`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I handtyped the code since it won't let me copy and paste but it's options on both the string and if else statement and I still can't limit the user by using health <60;

Comment: I added a link showing how to compare Strings using Java

Comment: @ScaryWombat I changed it to a .equals()  still doesn't help me limit the health which is my main question.

Comment: Show us your attempt with `health < 60` condition, and also the error you receive

Comment: If you converted the `String` to an `int`  [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) then you could do numeric comparison.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I tried doing that it would highlight the option = input.nextLine (); in red and then I changed that to an int too but then it would highlight the .equals(); you suggested earlier

Comment: If you are taking integer as a input don't use nextLine, use nextInt method. Or otherwise cast the string to integer by Integer.parseInt()

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first you need to convert a String to an `int` see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Also you are missing `;` and 
what does `health < 60` even mean?

Try this code

```
String option;
System.out.println("pick an option ");
System.out.println(" Option 1 feed cat ");
System.out.println(" Option 2 play with cat");
System.out.println(" Option 3 give cat bath");
option = input.nextLine();
if(Integer.valueOf(option) == 1) {

    if (health >= 60) {
        food += 10;
        happiness -= 15;  // where did this requirement come from?  Should it be +=?
    } else {
        happiness -=2;
    }
} else if (Integer.valueOf(option) == 2) {
    happiness += 12;
    health += 25;
}
```

**Of course** you should ensure that `option` can be converted to an `int` first

Comment: @PeterRader I will fix that, but as you know, and as per the javadocs, *this method returns an Integer object equal to the value of:

    new Integer(Integer.parseInt(s))*

Comment: @PeterRader *only if health level is less than 60 they can feed it.*

Comment: @PeterRader LOL, I have no idea where the OP got `happiness -= 15;` from - will comment in code.

Comment: if the user has enough health hey can feed it and happiness will subtract -15 or if health <60then happiness will subtract by 2 if they attempt to feed it

Comment: @new_coder01 OK I have fixed the code as per your above statement